# Ballerina Native Build Returns an Error for UUID Package

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I am in the process of utilizing ballerina native build in my microservice. The native build fails with the following log.

```
ERROR [ballerina/uuid/1.3.0::/root/.ballerina/repositories/central.ballerina.io/bala/ballerina/uuid/1.3.0/java11/modules/uuid/utils.bal:(23:28,23:46)] '0x8000000000000000' is out of range for 'int'
ERROR [ballerina/uuid/1.3.0::/root/.ballerina/repositories/central.ballerina.io/bala/ballerina/uuid/1.3.0/java11/modules/uuid/utils.bal:(23:28,23:46)] '0x8000000000000000' is out of range for 'int'
```

The dependencies.toml refers to the following `uuid` module/s

```
[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "uuid"
version = "1.3.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "crypto"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "lang.int"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "regex"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "time"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "ballerina", packageName = "uuid", moduleName = "uuid"}
]
```

The Dockerfile is as follows.

```
FROM ubuntu AS ballerina-builder
USER root
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install wget curl build-essential libz-dev zlib1g-dev && \
    wget https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/2201.3.2/ballerina-2201.3.2-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb && \
    dpkg -i ballerina-2201.3.2-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb && rm ballerina-2201.3.2-swan-lake-linux-x64.deb && \
    curl -sL https://get.graalvm.org/jdk >install-graalvm.sh && chmod a+x install-graalvm.sh && ./install-graalvm.sh && \
    export PATH="/src/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1/bin:$PATH" && export JAVA_HOME="/src/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1" && \
    bal build --native

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.14.1_1-alpine
WORKDIR /home/ballerina

RUN addgroup troupe \
    && adduser -S -s /bin/bash -g 'ballerina' -G troupe -D ballerina \
    && apk add --update --no-cache bash \
    && apk update && apk add --upgrade busybox libcrypto1.1 libssl1.1 \ 
    && chown -R ballerina:troupe /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY --from=ballerina-builder /src/target/bin/myservice.api.jar /home/ballerina
COPY --from=ballerina-builder /src/Config.toml /home/ballerina
RUN chown ballerina /home/ballerina/myservice.api.jar

USER ballerina

CMD java -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MinRAMPercentage=75.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0 -jar myservice.api.jar \
    || cat ballerina-internal.log
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraalVM native-image build is supported in Ballerina `2201.3.0`(SwanLake) or greater. So the GraalVM compatible `uuid` version is `1.4.0`.

Your `Dependencies.toml` has been updated with a lower version. This might be because you have build it locally with a Ballerina version lower than `2201.3.0`.

In the docker file you are pulling Ballerina `2201.3.2`. So I believe the error you mentioned is thrown from the compiler. This is expected as your `Dependencies.toml` is pointing to the incompatible versions. You can try by deleting the `Dependencies.toml` or update it with the version used in the docker file.

In addition to the above issue, the GraalVM version pulled in the docker file is incompatible with Ballerina. You should install GraalVM java 11 supported version with native-image build tool and set `GRAALVM_HOME`.

Ballerina provides a `--cloud` option to generate the docker file for you. You could use `bal build --native --cloud=docker`. For more information, see [`Build a native executable`](https://ballerina.io/learn/build-a-native-executable/#pack-the-native-executable-in-a-container).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

"So the GraalVM compatible uuid version is 1.4.0"

could you please point me where I can find this information? I checked the ballerina API docs: https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/uuid/1.4.0 and couldn't find such information there.

Comment: The ballerina modules are not yet marked as `GraalVM compatible` in the central or in the API docs. There is a [plan](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/39514) to mark them in the websites and give warnings if you are building with incompatible modules. So for now you can check in the central whether the module is compatible with Ballerina 2201.3.0 or greater - See `Ballerina compatibility` in https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/uuid

Comment: what I described was something more general. I want to know which versions of a package are compatible with a given ballerina release.

Comment: @SachithKasthuriarachchi When you select a specific version of a module in the ballerina central, you can see a section as
```
Ballerina compatibility
Platform: java11

Ballerina version: 2201.5.0
```